# Dapper invalid type owner

Tags: c#, dapper

I was just trying out Dapper for the very first time.

When I try to execute a query like the following, I encounter an ArgumentException "invalid type owner for DynamicMethod". Unlinke in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705325/dapper-execute-a-command-multiple-times-and-linq-and-toarray) question, inserts work just fine when using Execute().

```cs
var parameters = new[] { new { accountName = name, accountPassword = password } };
var accounts = connection.Query<Account>(@"SELECT * FROM " + this.TableName + " WHERE name = @accountName AND password = @accountPassword", parameters);
```

I am building against .NET 4.5 on Win7.

Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried passing `parameters` in as basic anonymous type (not in an array)?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! I cayrried this over from the insert example ^^ Care to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'll have to check where that exception message comes from, but I'm glad the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your parameters should just be:

```
var parameters = new { accountName = name, accountPassword = password };
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with the new[] new

Comment: Thank you and @chappoo for this hint. Carried it over from the insert example. But of course, it doesn't make sense here. Thanks a lot!